# I need help with set notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose, $x$ is a real number, $f(x)$ and $\gamma(x)$ are two different functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Now, suppose we take a fixed value $\bar{x}$ and evaluate $\gamma$ at $\bar{x}$. I want to say that for all $x$ values which are greater than $\bar{x}$, the following will hold: $f(x) \geq \gamma(\bar{x})$.

- Is there a particular name(or concept) for this kind of functions or sets;
- Can I equivalently say, $\nexists x>\bar{x}:f(x) \geq \gamma(\bar{x})$;
- How can I improve this notation?

Comment: Is $x$ a set or an element of a set? How are $f$ and $\gamma$ defined? What are you using $\gt$ for? Re: your question about notation: it's not even entirely clear what the question is! Forget about notation and see if you can render the question in nice plain English first. Then we'll worry about notation

Comment: @H.sapiensrex I am neither English, nor mathematician. I tried to clarify the details above. Thanks for having a look and your comment.

Comment: *I want to say ... the following will hold:* --- I'm not sure what you want, because this sentence seems fine to me (modulo some slight vagueness with "all $x$ values"). **(for ordinary human consumption)** For all $x \in \mathbb R,$ if $x > \bar{x}$ then $f(x) \geq \gamma(\bar{x}).$ **(for machine consumption)** $(\forall x)(((x \in \mathbb R) \wedge (x > \bar{x})) \implies f(x) \geq \gamma(\bar{x})).$ By the way, a seemingly stronger statement (but actually equivalent) can be made by replacing $x > \bar{x}$ with $x \geq \bar{x}.$ "Seemingly stronger" is because I've weakened the hypothesis.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I am not a mathematician. I have just recently fell in love with it. I try to adopt math formalities. Indeed, I like the fact that with math language you can speak to  math people of other countries without actually speaking their language. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x>y$ whenever $f(x)\geq g(y)$ is not equivalent to

$\neg\exists_{x,y}[x>y \land f(x)\geq g(y)] $

The latter is equivalent to

$\forall_{x,y}[\neg[x>y] \lor \neg[f(x)\geq g(y)]$

Which is equivalent to

$\forall_{x,y}[x > y \implies f(x)< g(y)]$

Or

$\forall_{x,y}[f(x)\geq g(y) \implies x\leq y]$

But you wanted

$\forall_{x,y}[f(x)\geq g(y) \implies x>y]$

So maybe you can compare these two expressions and figure out how to adjust your proposed equivalence. As for a name of this type of relationship, if you rewrite it as

$\forall_{x,y}[x\leq y \implies f(x)<g(y)]$

Then in the special case where $x=y$ we see that

$\forall_{x}[f(x)<g(x)]$

So $f$ is everywhere less than $g$. This is a necessary condition, but not sufficient, consider $f(x) = \cos(x)-\frac{1}{2}$ and $g(x) = \cos(x)$. This satisfies $f(x)<g(x)$ but it does not satisfy your condition. I don't think there is a much nicer way to describe this, as you can have very strange looking $f$ and $g$ satisfying this as long as the supremum of the range of $f$ exists and is less than the infimum of the range of $g$

Comment: The direction of implication that the OP was interested in has changed since the last edit, I will however leave my answer as is